# Command Prompt Scrolling down on typing

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, command-line

I got a weird problem with my command promt. When typing the screen is scrolling down so I can't see what I'm typing anymore. The problem just appears when I'm connected to the vServer (ubuntu 20) and not on windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it with typing `alias clear='clear -x'` in the shell. Now on clearing/typing it jumps right where it should.